# PHP Checks values from XML file in database

Tags: php, xml

I have several entries in XML file with "special number".

I have to search the database for these values.

If the number was not found in the database, then this "special number" and associated data should be stored in the database.

```
<?php
foreach($array_from_xml_file as $key => $value) {

    if($key === 'special_nummer'){

        $sql = $db->loadArray("SELECT email FROM table WHERE special_nummer = $value");

            // If nothing found insert new Data.

        if(empty($sql)){
            $insert_data = $db->insertData("INSERT INTO table (special_nummer, title, content) VALUES ('$key','$value','....')");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Disadvantage of this founction places a heavy load on the database.

My second method

I load the whole column with "special numbers" from database into an XML file or array.

Find the numbers that are not in the database and create a new array. Save this array to database.

My question: How do I make it most efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
foreach($array_from_xml_file as $key => $value) {
    if($key === 'special_nummer'){
        $insert_data = $db->insertData("INSERT IGNORE INTO table (special_nummer, title, content) VALUES ('$key','$value','....')");
    }
}
```

`special_nummer` has to be primary key or unique